# Two Devise Models, With Association Issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I have two models for devise.  Client, and Engineer.

The Client belongs to the Engineer.  From the Engineer#show page, I'm trying to link to the client but I'm getting a devise mapping error.

```
Could not find devise mapping for path "/clients/10".
```

I have two controllers, one for devise and one regular (controllers/client/registration_controller and controllers/client_controller)

My routes file looks like this...

```
  devise_for :clients, :controllers => {:registrations => "client/registrations"}
     resources :clients, :only => [:show, :new, :create]
  devise_for :engineers, :controllers => {:registrations => "engineer/registrations"}
     resources :engineers, :only => [:show]
  devise_scope :client do
     get "clients/:id", to: "clients#show" 
  end
```

Are the resources :clients competing with the scope declaration?

For good measure my rake routes:

```
      new_client_session GET    /clients/sign_in(.:format)         devise/sessions#new
          client_session POST   /clients/sign_in(.:format)         devise/sessions#create
  destroy_client_session DELETE /clients/sign_out(.:format)        devise/sessions#destroy
         client_password POST   /clients/password(.:format)        devise/passwords#create
     new_client_password GET    /clients/password/new(.:format)    devise/passwords#new
    edit_client_password GET    /clients/password/edit(.:format)   devise/passwords#edit
                         PATCH  /clients/password(.:format)        devise/passwords#update
                         PUT    /clients/password(.:format)        devise/passwords#update
cancel_client_registration GET    /clients/cancel(.:format)          client/registrations#cancel
     client_registration POST   /clients(.:format)                 client/registrations#create
 new_client_registration GET    /clients/sign_up(.:format)         client/registrations#new
edit_client_registration GET    /clients/edit(.:format)            client/registrations#edit
                         PATCH  /clients(.:format)                 client/registrations#update
                         PUT    /clients(.:format)                 client/registrations#update
                         DELETE /clients(.:format)                 client/registrations#destroy
                 clients POST   /clients(.:format)                 clients#create
              new_client GET    /clients/new(.:format)             clients#new
                  client GET    /clients/:id(.:format)             clients#show
    new_engineer_session GET    /engineers/sign_in(.:format)       devise/sessions#new
        engineer_session POST   /engineers/sign_in(.:format)       devise/sessions#create
destroy_engineer_session DELETE /engineers/sign_out(.:format)      devise/sessions#destroy
       engineer_password POST   /engineers/password(.:format)      devise/passwords#create
   new_engineer_password GET    /engineers/password/new(.:format)  devise/passwords#new
  edit_engineer_password GET    /engineers/password/edit(.:format) devise/passwords#edit
                         PATCH  /engineers/password(.:format)      devise/passwords#update
                         PUT    /engineers/password(.:format)      devise/passwords#update
                engineer GET    /engineers/:id(.:format)           engineers#show
                         GET    /clients/:id(.:format)             clients#show
                    root GET    /                                  pages#home
           pages_clients GET    /pages/clients(.:format)           pages#clients
         pages_engineers GET    /pages/engineers(.:format)         pages#engineers
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you should just drop your `devise_scope` block, since you have the following line:

```
resources :clients, :only => [:show, :new, :create]
```

This line already gives you `client_path`:

```
client GET    /clients/:id(.:format)             clients#show
```

but your `devise_scope` gives you a duplicate (but unnamed) path:

```
       GET    /clients/:id(.:format)             clients#show
```

So, your routes file should look like:

```
devise_for :clients, :controllers => {:registrations => "client/registrations"}
resources :clients, :only => [:show, :new, :create]
devise_for :engineers, :controllers => {:registrations => "engineer/registrations"}
resources :engineers, :only => [:show]
```

Comment: Yep, thanks.  This plus I was using the wrong controller inheritance... silly me XD